# XML file processing in R

Tags: r, xml, parsing

I'm a relatively experienced R user but I never worked with xml files. I could load an xml file with xml2::read_xml but I can't use the valid list object. The file is large to paste here, but I can paste here a sample of the file and a link. This is a hierarchical report, the grouping variables are the "partitions", the fields are the "fields" in witch are the values of interest. My goal is to make a dataframe from this data (or tibble, in long format).

The value attributes of a partition node should be the row names. Yes, these are nested, that means there are more columns with names, subnames, sub-sub names etc. which are important. (The foremost or last three column should be the universe node's name, startdat and enddate attributes.) The type attribute of field nodes should be the column names of my table and cell's values are the numbers of field's.

Finally, here is a link to the whole file (7-zipped xml): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LlnX6mePzd73rk9kitEBmi_yEjKQRs2i/view?usp=sharing

And a screenshot of xlxs output format:
[image: screenshot]

Sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<results xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    reportname="IQ performance" startdate="11/30/2020" enddate="2/26/2021">
    <universe id="U-0001" dateid="D-0001" name="U-0001"
        startdate="11/30/2020" enddate="12/31/2020">
        <partition id="P-0001" type="6924700104024916117" value="All"
            bucketnum="-1">
            <field id="A-0008" type="Excess Return (MSR)">0.07676352900773953</field>
            <field id="A-0013" type="Total Return Lcl Ccy">0.04057259532874724</field>
            <field id="A-0006" type="Coupon Return">0.14286550062017067</field>
            <field id="A-0012" type="Total Return">-0.9958805536684379</field>
            <field id="A-0010" type="Prepay Penalty Return">0</field>
            <field id="A-0009" type="Paydown Return">0</field>
            <field id="A-0007" type="Currency Return">-1.0364531489970519</field>
            <field id="A-0011" type="Price Return">-0.10229316638965535</field>
            <field id="A-0015" type="S/A Yield">0.004483473613543104</field>
            <field id="A-0001" type="Number of Instruments">6453</field>
            <field id="A-0005" type="MktVal HLDS">19482017305.036118</field>
            <field id="A-0002" type="Index Rating BOM">AA2/AA3</field>
            <field id="A-0004" type="Market Value Previous Month">19427649084.733593</field>
            <field id="A-0014" type="OAD">3.7185477934428124</field>
            <field id="A-0016" type="OAS (To Worst)">0.20330610590838008</field>
            <field id="A-0003" type="Market Value BOM">19856386358.19814</field>
        </partition>
        <partition id="P-0001" type="6924700104024916117" value="Others"
            bucketnum="01_14">
            <partition id="P-0001" type="6924700104024916117" value="EUR"
                bucketnum="02_02">
                <partition id="P-0001" type="6924700104024916117"
                    value="Credit" bucketnum="11_3">
                    <partition id="P-0001" type="6924700104024916117"
                        value="Short" bucketnum="21_1">
                        <field id="A-0008" type="Excess Return (MSR)">0.07183258338108178</field>
                        <field id="A-0013" type="Total Return Lcl Ccy">0.01214342353634823</field>
                        <field id="A-0006" type="Coupon Return">0.31482269238130023</field>
                        <field id="A-0012" type="Total Return">0.01214342353634823</field>
                        <field id="A-0010" type="Prepay Penalty Return"></field>
                        <field id="A-0009" type="Paydown Return">0</field>
                        <field id="A-0007" type="Currency Return">0</field>
                        <field id="A-0011" type="Price Return">-0.3026896289808234</field>
                        <field id="A-0015" type="S/A Yield">-0.4928755405648736</field>
                        <field id="A-0001" type="Number of Instruments">2</field>
                        <field id="A-0005" type="MktVal HLDS">2548003.4519999996</field>
                        <field id="A-0002" type="Index Rating BOM">AA2/AA3</field>
                        <field id="A-0004" type="Market Value Previous Month">2544467.735</field>
                        <field id="A-0014" type="OAD">0.32466544675466164</field>
                        <field id="A-0016" type="OAS (To Worst)">0.22419945895458546</field>
                        <field id="A-0003" type="Market Value BOM">2547694.23</field>
                    </partition>
                    <partition id="P-0001" type="6924700104024916117"
                        value="Intermediate" bucketnum="22_2">
                        <field id="A-0008" type="Excess Return (MSR)">0.8805662483038379</field>
                        <field id="A-0013" type="Total Return Lcl Ccy">0.7722013521882509</field>
                        <field id="A-0006" type="Coupon Return">0.17896670856365482</field>
                        <field id="A-0012" type="Total Return">0.7722013521882509</field>
                        <field id="A-0010" type="Prepay Penalty Return"></field>
                        <field id="A-0009" type="Paydown Return">0</field>
                        <field id="A-0007" type="Currency Return">0</field>
                        <field id="A-0011" type="Price Return">0.5932365519324856</field>
                        <field id="A-0015" type="S/A Yield">0.345214292489727</field>
                        <field id="A-0001" type="Number of Instruments">5</field>
                        <field id="A-0005" type="MktVal HLDS">4722524.7425</field>
                        <field id="A-0002" type="Index Rating BOM">A1/A2</field>
                        <field id="A-0004" type="Market Value Previous Month">4652650.297499999</field>
                        <field id="A-0014" type="OAD">4.400948577468358</field>
                        <field id="A-0016" type="OAS (To Worst)">1.0808156019106423</field>
                        <field id="A-0003" type="Market Value BOM">4686336.749</field>
                    </partition>
                    <partition id="P-0001" type="6924700104024916117"
                        value="All" bucketnum="-1">
                        <field id="A-0008" type="Excess Return (MSR)">0.5957449505084811</field>
                        <field id="A-0013" type="Total Return Lcl Ccy">0.5045227640105621</field>
                        <field id="A-0006" type="Coupon Return">0.22681271683868687</field>
                        <field id="A-0012" type="Total Return">0.5045227640105621</field>
                        <field id="A-0010" type="Prepay Penalty Return"></field>
                        <field id="A-0009" type="Paydown Return">0</field>
                        <field id="A-0007" type="Currency Return">0</field>
                        <field id="A-0011" type="Price Return">0.2777076347568519</field>
                        <field id="A-0015" type="S/A Yield">0.051500310426545876</field>
                        <field id="A-0001" type="Number of Instruments">7</field>
                        <field id="A-0005" type="MktVal HLDS">7270528.194499999</field>
                        <field id="A-0002" type="Index Rating BOM">AA3/A1</field>
                        <field id="A-0004" type="Market Value Previous Month">7197118.032499999</field>
                        <field id="A-0014" type="OAD">2.9723888895704493</field>
                        <field id="A-0016" type="OAS (To Worst)">0.7806089551718131</field>
                        <field id="A-0003" type="Market Value BOM">7234030.979</field>
                    </partition>
                </partition>
                <partition id="P-0001" type="6924700104024916117" value="All"
                    bucketnum="-1">
                    <field id="A-0008" type="Excess Return (MSR)">0.5957449505084811</field>
                    <field id="A-0013" type="Total Return Lcl Ccy">0.5045227640105621</field>
                    <field id="A-0006" type="Coupon Return">0.22681271683868687</field>
                    <field id="A-0012" type="Total Return">0.5045227640105621</field>
                    <field id="A-0010" type="Prepay Penalty Return"></field>
                    <field id="A-0009" type="Paydown Return">0</field>
                    <field id="A-0007" type="Currency Return">0</field>
                    <field id="A-0011" type="Price Return">0.2777076347568519</field>
                    <field id="A-0015" type="S/A Yield">0.051500310426545876</field>
                    <field id="A-0001" type="Number of Instruments">7</field>
                    <field id="A-0005" type="MktVal HLDS">7270528.194499999</field>
                    <field id="A-0002" type="Index Rating BOM">AA3/A1</field>
                    <field id="A-0004" type="Market Value Previous Month">7197118.032499999</field>
                    <field id="A-0014" type="OAD">2.9723888895704493</field>
                    <field id="A-0016" type="OAS (To Worst)">0.7806089551718131</field>
                    <field id="A-0003" type="Market Value BOM">7234030.979</field>
                </partition>
            </partition>
            <partition id="P-0001" type="6924700104024916117" value="All"
                bucketnum="-1">
                <field id="A-0008" type="Excess Return (MSR)">0.5957449505084811</field>
                <field id="A-0013" type="Total Return Lcl Ccy">0.5045227640105621</field>
                <field id="A-0006" type="Coupon Return">0.22681271683868687</field>
                <field id="A-0012" type="Total Return">0.5045227640105621</field>
                <field id="A-0010" type="Prepay Penalty Return"></field>
                <field id="A-0009" type="Paydown Return">0</field>
                <field id="A-0007" type="Currency Return">0</field>
                <field id="A-0011" type="Price Return">0.2777076347568519</field>
                <field id="A-0015" type="S/A Yield">0.051500310426545876</field>
                <field id="A-0001" type="Number of Instruments">7</field>
                <field id="A-0005" type="MktVal HLDS">7270528.194499999</field>
                <field id="A-0002" type="Index Rating BOM">AA3/A1</field>
                <field id="A-0004" type="Market Value Previous Month">7197118.032499999</field>
                <field id="A-0014" type="OAD">2.9723888895704493</field>
                <field id="A-0016" type="OAS (To Worst)">0.7806089551718131</field>
                <field id="A-0003" type="Market Value BOM">7234030.979</field>
            </partition>
        </partition>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I can't use the valid list object". What do you need to do? The data you posted doesn't look very data-frame like so it's unclear what a data.frame for this data might look like. XML can be a highly nested format while data.frames are primarily designed for holding rectangular data with equal numbers of rows and columns.

Comment: The list object doesn't contain the values but partitions and fields are there. The data is not a simple rectangular one - perhaps in this case I could solve my task. This is like an pivot table in Excel, with summary rows, so I think it should be good for a long dataframe.

Comment: You have partition nodes within partition nodes within partition nodes.  Your problem description is not very clear what data you would like to extract.  Is it just the field nodes without the partition information?

Comment: Thanks @Dave2e. I edited the original post: made some clarification and attached a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm on track to the solution. It's untested, It could be more flexible but I share it now:

```
library(XML)
library(dplyr)

mydoc <- xmlParse("file:///path/to/my/weird.xml")

newcols <- c("report", "rep_start_dt", "rep_end_dt", 
             "universe id", "dateid", NA,
             "startdate", "enddate",
             "partition id", NA, "region", "bucketnum1",
             NA, NA, "currency", "bucketnum2",
             NA, NA, "sector", "bucketnum3",
             NA, NA, "maturity", "bucketnum4",
             "field id", "field")

rawdata <- bind_cols(
    path = xpathSApply(mydoc, path="/results/universe/partition/partition/partition/partition/field", function(y)paste(unlist( xmlAncestors(y, fun=xmlAttrs)), collapse="|")),
    value = xpathSApply(mydoc, path="/results/universe/partition/partition/partition/partition/field", xmlValue)
) %>% 
    tidyr::separate(path, into = newcols, sep = "\\|", convert = FALSE) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(rep_start_dt, rep_end_dt, startdate, enddate), lubridate::mdy)

DBI::sqlAppendTable(DBI::ANSI(), "iq_report", rawdata, row.names = FALSE) %>% write(file = bzfile("iq_report.sql.bz2"))
closeAllConnections()
```

If you have comment, please share it.
Peter